# Undefined reference to object's method

Tags: c++, qt

I am making app in `c++` which is creating gui and writing data into descriptors. At first I created `_window` which is handler to my gui. Next I created `_conn` which is object used to write data. I want to have `conn` in `_window` so I assigned it.

Now, I want to send some data when I click the button. The problem is I cant even compile the code - I am getting error:

```
error: undefined reference to `conn::writeData(int, char*, int)'
```

Cant really tell what is wrong. When I put debugging point in this line it still not compiling. When I delete this line - code is compiling.

This is my code:

```
//main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow _window;
    conn * _conn = new conn(argc, argv);
    _window._conn = _conn;
}

//conn.h
class conn
{
public:
    conn(int argc, char ** argv);
    int sock;
    void writeData(int fd, char * buffer, int count);
};

//conn.cpp
void writeData(int fd, char * buffer, int count){
    //TODO
}

//mainwindow.h
public:
    conn * _conn;


//mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //_conn->writeData(_conn->sock, "hello", 5);
}
```

Comment: You have defined function `writeData` in cpp file, you should define member  function of class `void conn::writeData` in your cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have linking error as you don't implement `conn::writeData`.

```
void writeData(int fd, char * buffer, int count){
    //TODO
}
```

should be

```
void conn::writeData(int fd, char * buffer, int count){
    //TODO
}
```